# How to reduce number of expansions of second argument in 2-dimensional _Generic?

Tags: c, generics, c11

I have the following code:

```
int add_ii(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
unsigned add_iu(int a, unsigned b) { return a + b; }
unsigned add_ui(unsigned a, int b) { return a + b; }
unsigned add_uu(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return a + b; }

#define add(LEFT, RIGHT) \
    _Generic(LEFT \
        ,int: _Generic(RIGHT \
           ,int:      add_ii \
           ,unsigned: add_iu \
        ) \
        ,unsigned: _Generic(RIGHT \
           ,int:      add_ui \
           ,unsigned: add_uu \
        ) \
    )(LEFT, RIGHT)

int main() {
     return add(1, add(2, add(3, 4)));
}
```

The problem is that `RIGHT` is expanded for each `_Generic` case. In the above, `RIGHT` is used 3 times, so `add(2, add(3, 4))` is fully expanded 3 times, so `add(3, 4)` is expanded 9 times. The number grows exponentially with each nested usage and with each additional type handled inside `_Generic`. This is not an issue in itself - but it causes preprocessor to generate *very big* output, which *significantly* stalls the compilation process and causes *very high* compilation memory usage.

Is there any way to write 2-dimensional `_Generic` so that `RIGHT` is not expanded each time for each type?

Switching `LEFT` with `RIGHT` is of course not an option and wouldn't do much - `LEFT` will be then expanded that many times.

I know I can use GNU extensions, but the idea is that I would like to do without them:

```
#define add(LEFT, RIGHT0)  ({
    __auto_type LEFT = LEFT0;
    __auto_type RIGHT = RIGHT0;
    _Generic(LEFT, .....)(LEFT, RIGHT)
})
```

I can write kind of a map, but that erases return type information and requires all function types to be cast to a common type, or to use some unsafe `va_arg`:

```
unsigned add_ii_adaptor(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return add_ii(a, b); }
unsigned add_iu_adaptor(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return add_iu(a, b); }
unsigned add_ui_adaptor(unsigned a, unsigned b) { return add_ui(a, b); }
static unsigned (*const funcarr[])(unsigned a, unsigned b) = {
    add_ii_adaptor,
    add_iu_adaptor,
    add_ui_adaptor,
    add_uu,
};
#define typeidx(x)  _Generic((x), int: 0, unsigned 1)
#define add(LEFT, RIGHT)  \
     funcarr[typeidx(LEFT) << 1 | typeidx(RIGHT)](LEFT, RIGHT)
```

Is there a method that I'm overlooking?

Background: `However, what is the ultimate point here?` I'm implementing [Integer safety n2792](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2792.pdf) without GNU extensions [here](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/ckd). There are 26 types I want to support, `ckd_add(x, y, z)` makes it 17576 combinations of types. (This can be reduced, but nonetheless). In the examples above the return type is the promoted type of operands, so `unsigned + int = unsigned`, but like for example it could be `long + char = long *or unsigned long!*`.

Comment: note that solution with `funcarr` will still grow exponentially due to expanding both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` twice. Is is still good enough?

Comment: To start, rearrange `add(1, add(2, add(3, 4))` to `add(add(1, 2), add(3, 4))`. However, what is the ultimate point here? It would seem like you have to know the result type at some point, because ultimately it must be used in some assignment or `return` or other point where the type is fixed, unless it is passed as an argument to a variable-argument function. And then, if you know the result type (`unsigned` if any operand is `unsigned`, `int` otherwise), you could just do all the arithmetic in that type from the start.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I guess `int`, `unsigned` and `add` is used to somehow abstract the original problem to help people focus on the crucial part of the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible use `_Generic` with mapping a tuple to an integer. You need a type parameterized by an integer and C provides such a family ... arrays.
However, arrays cannot be used as dispatched argument because an array decays to pointer. However, pointers to arrays *do not* decay.

Just compute a size of array using `typeidx`-like macro and use is as a size of an new array type. Add `1` because C forbids zero-size arrays.

Next form a pointer to it using compound literal.
E.q. `(int(*)[3]) { 0 }`.
Finally, use the type of this literal to dispatch a proper function pointer.

```
#define TYPE_TO_NUM(X) _Generic((X), int: 0, unsigned: 1)

#define add(LEFT, RIGHT) \
    _Generic(        \
        (int(*)[1 + 2 * TYPE_TO_NUM(LEFT) + TYPE_TO_NUM(RIGHT)]) { 0 } \
        ,int(*)[1]: add_ii \
        ,int(*)[2]: add_iu \
        ,int(*)[3]: add_ui \
        ,int(*)[4]: add_uu \
        )(LEFT, RIGHT)
```

The solution still has exponential complexity due to expanding `LEFT` and `RIGHT` twice but is far faster than the original one.

Comment: Nice solution. You could also just write the compound literal as `&(int[...]){0}` to get slightly less intimidating syntax.

Comment: Omg, this is an amazing idea! Thank You! I will test it and then get back to you, it will take me some time to refactor the code.

Comment: @KamilCuk, there was a minor type in code (extra `2 *`), fixed